# How to get library of devise so that it can be modified like php libraries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-confirmable

Getting the generated devise controller like.

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
   before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

  # GET /resource/sign_in
   def new
    # super
        #       byebug
        redirect_to  root_url   
   end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
   def create
        puts 'Login user............'        
        super
        puts '..............'

   end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
   def destroy
     super
   end

  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
   def configure_sign_in_params
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])
   end
end
```

where can I get the library of devise so that I can modify it new function and do not get error of double redirect.

suppose in terminal logs out put is as Processing by

```
Users::SessionsController#new as HTML
```

where is the code written for method new in its devise library.

Comment: devise is configurable with the methods it uses, if you tell us what you are trying to achieve with devise, we can give you a solution, please edit with the information about what you are trying to do with devise

Comment: If you're talking about customizing what devise provides for your requirements, then yes you can. I'm not sure when you say _modified_, please provide more information on what you want to achieve, so we can suggest, if the modification is needed or it could be that devise already provides what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you mean
In the devise model you have to make something like this

```
   before_create :welcome_alert
   before_create :confirm_email
   after_save :subscribe_user_to_mailing_list

def welcome_alert
    alert = ("signed_up_but_unconfirmed")
  end

  def confirm_email
    UserMailer.registration_confirmation(self).deliver
  end
```

Is this what you want!